# Touch button on DWIN DGUS Software for switching pages and incrementing value both

Tags: touch, touch-event

On my DGUS software, I need a touch button which sends a message to the microcontroller (to perform a task) and also switches between pages. Which functionality under "Touch Control" should I use?

I tried Basic Touch control (to switch page) and Increment Adjustment (to send message) but they overlap and only one happens which is on the top.

Answer (score 0):

You must use "-Return key code", check Data auto-uploading and in page switching choose destination page. VP will be your variable address, key value will be value which will be store in this address after pressing the area. If VP = 2000, key value = 2001 display return through RS232 when you press area-  5A A5 06 83 20 00 01 20 01
if VP = 2222 KeyValue = 000A ---->  5A A5 06 83 22 22 01 00 0A